# Get a user id from a mention

Tags: discord.py

I search how I can get a user id from a mention (from other user, not me). I tried to do this with split():
`bet1=message.content.split(" ")[1]`
`bet1=message.content.split("<")[1]`
`bet1=message.content.split("@")[1]`
but that is not working because he reads after the from one splited symbol to the next same
`bet1=message.content.split(">")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions).

```py
if message.mentions: #check if message has any mentions
    if isinstance(message.mentions[0], discord.Member) or isinstance(message.mentions[0], discord.User): #checking if the first mention is of a User or a Member (User in server)
        await message.channel.send(message.mentions[0].id)
```